# Выполнение запроса из c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть программа на asp.net. Выполняю запрос из кода. Вот как обрабатываю его:

```
public static double QualityValueFromSingleRow(OracleConnection dbConnection, String sql, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("START_DATE", startDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("END_DATE", endDate);
            using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Вот как записан сам запрос:

```
"select sum(nvl(OTLIVKA_T,0)) from vpo.SPP_MARTEN_KOVSH where PECH = 7 and DATE1 between :START_DATE and :END_DATE"
```

Все параметры привязаны. В sql-developer запрос выполняется и даёт конкретный результат. Число если быть точнее. Почему из кода c#, перечесление не даёт результатов, как написано в ридере. Может я что то не вижу. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Так приведите код, который не работает.

Comment: @tym32167 `using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rdr[0].ToString()))
                        return Convert.ToDouble(rdr[0]);
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }`

Comment: @tym32167 на строчке `rdr.read()` не проходит чтение. Как будто нет результатов. Хотя реально запрос выдаёт результат.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, добавьте это в вопрос :). В комментариях это просто нечитаемо.

Comment: @tym32167 попробовал сделать тоже самое с помощью дата адаптера вместо ридера. И записал в дата тейбл всё заработало. В чём может быть прикол ридера?